# Streaming XPS Bytes to the Print Document Package API

Tags: c++, winapi, printing, desktop, xps

I'm looking to print an XPS document from a C++ desktop application. The source of the XPS actually comes from a conversion from PDF to XPS, and we're able to get a stream of the XPS bytes as it's being converted.

From this point of view, we'd like to be able to stream the converted XPS bytes directly into the [Print Document Package API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/printdocs/tailored-app-printing-api), in order to print it to a local printer.

Note: This is assuming that the XPS Print API is deprecated, as per the documentation

It seems fairly straight forward to call [IPrintDocumentPackageTargetFactory::CreateDocumentPackageTargetForPrintJob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/documenttarget/nf-documenttarget-iprintdocumentpackagetargetfactory-createdocumentpackagetargetforprintjob), which takes an IStream, which the MSDN documentation suggests should be the content of the document. But streaming my bytes to the IStream that I pass in doesn't seem to do anything (no job added to the queue, etc).

The only alternative is to use the other interfaces in the Print Document Package APIs and send the XPS in parts instead, but this would be a large amount of work to convert the bytes we output back into XPS parts.

Any suggestions?

**Update:**

Looks like the content stream is for output only. If set, it provides a stream of bytes that represent the XPS commands being issued. If it's set to null, it routes through the Windows Print System and onto the printer instead.

Comment: Have you seen this sample: https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/master/Samples/D2DPrintingFromDesktopApps/cpp/D2DPrintingFromDesktopApps.cpp

Comment: Hey @SimonMourier, thanks for the link, but this looks like it uses the ID2DPrintControl class, which allows Direct X commands to be streamed to the print sub-system. I'm not sure this helps?

Comment: It demonstrates how to create the stream you're having issues with, using this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/prntvpt/nf-prntvpt-ptconvertdevmodetoprintticket

Comment: Hi, @Andy, you could [add your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and then [accept](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) instead of editing it in the question.

Comment: @SimonMourier, I'm not sure I'm following. I have a stream of XPS bytes, which I'm trying to send to the Windows print system and onwards to a printer. The sample seems to take DirectX commands and queue them up to be replayed to a separate class which turns then into XPS parts. The devmode to print ticket conversion is useful, but not in this scenario. I already have print tickets embedded inside my XPS document.

Comment: @DrakeWu-MSFT, I'm not sure I've got an answer yet? :) One answer could be 'no, there is no API to allow a developer to stream XPS bytes in the Print Document Package APIs, you can only stream XPS parts.' I'm not sure I know enough about the API surface area to say that yet.

Comment: @Andy, do I need to fully convert a existing Legacy Desktop App (c++) to a UWP app in order to support Print Document Package API?

Comment: @Andrew, you shouldn't need to. The Print document package API is a C++ Win32 API. This answer here may help you too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68722953/187100